# parse multi dimensiona json array android

Tags: android, json

I've been having problems on parsing JSON and I'm stuck on a particular situation.
I'm trying to get all values under a JSON arrat "details" but it's giving me an errors tha says JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

```
{
"response": "true",
"errors": "<span>Success</span>",
"details": {
    "sid": "15",
    "pid": "1",
    "user_email": "chardalvarez@gmail.com",
```

Here's what I've already done:

```
String json = mParser.makeHttpRequest(API_REGISTER, "POST", params);
        Log.d("Registration Return: ", json);

        try { 
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            if (jObj != null) {
                mDetails = jObj.getJSONArray("details");

                if (mDetails != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mDetails.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = mDetails.getJSONObject(i);

                        mPid = c.getString("sid");
                        mSid = c.getString("pid");
                        mUserEmail = c.getString("user_email");
```

But still I'm getting the same error. Am I doing it wrong with my code? I've also checked my JSON using [JSONLINT](http://jsonlint.com/) thinking that it was an invalid JSON but it says valid JSON. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `details` is JSONObject instead of JSONArray so use `jObj.getJSONObject("details");` to get details JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String json = mParser.makeHttpRequest(API_REGISTER, "POST", params);
        Log.d("Registration Return: ", json);

        try { 
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            if (jObj != null) {
                mDetails = jObj.getJSONObject"details");

                if (mDetails != null) {
                        String sid= mDetails.getString("sid");
                        String pid = mDetails.getString("pid");
                        String mUserEmail = mDetails.getString("user_email");
```

Comment: As suggested by gaurav5430 I did try that before asking the question but somehow I got the same problem but this time in reverse! It says JSON Object cannot be converted in to JSON Array! So what I did is to remove the application on my phone and clean my project and then try again and what luck it worked! Thanks guys for helping me out on this one. Thank you gaurav5430 and Ajay Thakur for taking time to look on my problem here :)

Answer (score 1):

your json is valid, but `details` is a `JSON object` , not a `JSON array`

you are using a `curly brace` in details, which means it is an `object`

```
{
"response": "true",
"errors": "<span>Success</span>",
"details": {
    "sid": "15",
    "pid": "1",
    "user_email": "chardalvarez@gmail.com",
```

for array , replace the curly braces with `square brackets`

```
{
"response": "true",
"errors": "<span>Success</span>",
"details": [
    "sid": "15",
    "pid": "1",
    "user_email": "chardalvarez@gmail.com",
```

EDIT: looking at your code, it seems it more be more beneficial if details is an object, not an array

(also if you have an array, the values would just be stored as string values and not json key value pairs, according to your syntax)

so change from

```
mDetails = jObj.getJSONArray("details");
```

to

```
mDetails = jObj.getJSONObject("details");
```